# MongoDb data relations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have a:

- **MongoDB Database**
- **REST API on NodeJS**
- **Angular JS frontend**

Now I want to create Database schma. It will be:

**Story** - user insert story with descriptions.

**Questions** - relation to story. One story can have more than 100 questions.

**Answers** - relation to questions. One question can have onlye one answer.

What type of relation should I chose in MongoDb? I need faster soultion.
For example:

```
{
 title: "Story title",
 descr: "Story descr",
 questions: [
              {body: "Question body", user: "User}
            ]
}
```

Comment: Kudos for asking about schema design. So many folks start with MongoDB and implement 3NF (to their eventual unhappiness). +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the number of questions per story can be large and assuming it's not required to show all questions when showing the story (in particular when showing the list of stories), and because having a lot of writers to one document comes with a number of complexities, I'd suggest the following simple schema:

```
stories {
  _id
  title
  description
}

questions {
  _id
  storyId
  user
  body
  answer { ... }
}
```

Finding all questions for a story is simple (`storyId` should have an index), finding the story for a given question is trivial. I think the `answer` can be embedded. Still, be careful about concurrent writes, i.e. when someone edits the question while somebody else writes the answer. This is a lot easier when using a single embedded document than an for the array, and the number of concurrent writers is probably two at most, not potentially hundreds.

The only slightly more tricky operation is deletion of a story which requires you to manually delete the questions, but that's literally just a single call.

Comment: But if I want to retrive Story and Questions I have to make separated API calls?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'd *do* it, to keep things simple (also, you could do these in parallel which would be Angular's default behavior anyway). But if you really want to to, you can combine the query results on the server and send a combined DTO to the frontend. Or did you mean database operations by "API calls"? In that case, I wouldn't worry, they shouldn't be much slower than the single call and again, they can be parallelized because you reference the story id from the questions.

Comment: I see that You have a lot of experience in Mongo :) I will implement this way you suggest. I also want to implement vote system for stories, answers, questions. Should I create new collentios for this?

Comment: Hmm, that depends on the details... I assume a single user can only vote on an item once? If the number of votes is small, embedding the user ids might be okay, but a seperate votes collection is probably better.